# Why does a Firestore security rule using get() not work while another rule using resource.data works?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've been working on a chat app in order to get used to Cloud Firestore.
Below is the structure of its database.

```
rooms
  ├ xxxxxx
  │  ├ messages
  │  │  ├ xxxxxx
  │  │  └ xxxxxx
  │  └ private
  │      └ allowed - members [xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx]
  └ xxxxxx
      ├ messages
      │  ├ xxxxxx
      │  └ xxxxxx
      └ private
          └ allowed - members [xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx]
```

The `private` subcollection under each chat room document has a single document with `allowed` as its ID.
`allowed` has `members`, which is an array field holding IDs of users allowed to use the chat room.

What I have to do first to fetch a particular chat room is to get the `allowed` document, as follows:

```js
db.collectionGroup('private')
  .where('members', 'array-contains', userId)
  .get()
  .then(...)
```

I've already created an index on `private` for collection group queries, so the above code works.

However, if I add the following security rule, it fails with the error message of 'Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.'

```
match /{path=**}/private/{document} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid
    in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(path)/private/$(document)).data.members;
}
```

This rule is for forbidding a user from accessing `allowed` if not a member of the room.
A query without `.where(...)` results in the same error.

On the other hand, the rule below works as expected.

```
match /{path=**}/private/{document} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
}
```

I know this rule is by far better, so I'll definitely use it, but I still wonder why the previous rule didn't work.
Would anyone clarify the cause please?

---

[image]

- [Securely query data  |  Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters)

---

Is this possibly related in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Your security rule was written for a collectionGroup `/{path=**}/private`, for one thing - this rule, as written, applies to any collection named "private", regardless of where it is.  Also, you try to use the variable `$(rule)`, which I see no definition for.

Security rules only work with **matching queries** - you have to make sure your query *explicity* cannot result in a un-allowed document.  *IF* the query *could* result in an un-allowed document (i.e. as specified by the security rule), then the ENTIRE query will be rejected - not just the un-allowed document.  Security rules are all-or-nothing - that's why they scale.

Comment: Oops, it's my fault. I mistakenly pasted one of the rules I tried earlier, sorry! The actual `get()` part is `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(path)/private/$(document)).data.members;`, which doesn't work either.

Comment: As for the fact that rules only work with matching queries, I'd already noticed it and therefore pasted the screenshot of the related description. My question is, why does it affect my query? I guess `where('members', 'array-contains', userId)` is a condition for getting only an allowed document. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, I do know.  Security Rules can fetch *one* document in a .get().  But your query (above) *could* match *many* documents, since ${path=**} is ANY path followed by /private, and {document} in a collectionGroup query represents a *set* of documents, not just one.  I've run into this *kind* of issue (I use a lot of collectionGroups), and they can be *quite* tricky to get security rules correct.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds reasonable. From what I've understood from it, `.get(many documents).data.members` is an operation to get each `members` field from multiple objects in an array in an incorrect way; it is almost like `[{members: ['a', 'b']}, {members: ['a', 'b']}].members`, which is wrong in various programming languages.

Comment: Could you edit your answer so that I can select it as the best answer?