# Does a wildcard have to be used for the document segment in a matching path of a Firestore collection group security rule?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```js
db.collectionGroup('private')
  .where('members', 'array-contains', userId)
  .get()
  .then(...)
```

This query fetches documents successfully if the relevant security rule is set like:

```
match /{path=**}/private/{document} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
}
```

However, the similar rule below prevents the same query unexpectedly.

```
match /{path=**}/private/allowed {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
}
```

In this database,

- `private` subcollections exist only under documents in the `rooms` collection.
- Every `private` has only a single document with the ID "allowed".

This means `/rooms/xxxxxxxx/private/allowed` is the only possible path existing, where `xxxxxxxx` is an auto-assigned document ID.
Therefore specifying the path as `/{path=**}/private/allowed` looks correct to me.

In fact, "get" queries work in simulations in the playground, so is it a restriction only for collection group queries, or am I doing anything wrong?

FYI, more detailed database structure is described in another question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65600773/why-does-a-firestore-security-rule-using-get-not-work-while-another-rule-using/65603477#65603477).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is required.

When you perform a collection group query, it's not possible to call out a specific document id in the query (e.g. "allowed").  The query is explicitly asking to consider **all** of the documents in **all** of the subcollections of the given name ("private").  Therefore, the rules must allow for those documents to be considered by adding the trailing wildcard.

You can certainly add a filter to the query if you want to get only certain documents with certain field values, but that filter can't be enforced in the rules.